# Creating an application bundle on OSX with eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, xcode, makefile, debugging

I have compiled a project using Eclipse with C/C++ plugin (using http://libcinder.org library, and it's working pretty good. 
Sort of...

It is a windowed application, and opengl is correctly redrawing the screen, mouse events are correct, etc. However, I can only run the application from the terminal, otherwise when i attempt to hit debug I can see my console statements but there's no window to speak of.

When i output the CWD from the application, it appears to think it is running from my user directory.

How can I make this application seem more 'mac like', specifically when you rightclick a mac application you can view it's contents, and be able to load files relative to the applications executable.

Also, any insight as to why it does not appear when launching via debugger in eclipse would be helpful too.

I have put this project together for anyone else who might find it useful here:
https://github.com/onedayitwillmake/EclipseLovesCinder

Comment: Why was this question voted down, i feel that a lot of people would want to knwo this info and it turns out it is pretty straight forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm. This is an architecture problem. I don't know how resources are bundled by Eclipse normally, but they don't use the application bundle architecture that OSX has built in.

[Here's the Apple developer docs on NSBundle. Start your reading here!](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it's really a matter of just creating the directories.
I found some good information on this page:
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NUzzPvEcP04J:max.berger.name/howto/wxWidgets/wxWidgets_Eclipse.jsp+application+bundle+${BuildArtifactFileName}&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com

I'm specifically using this in the projects, C/C++ Build -> Settings -> BuildSteps -> Post Build Steps:

All one line, with ; between them
`mkdir -p ${BuildArtifactFileName}.app/Contents/MacOS ;

mv ${BuildArtifactFileName}  ${BuildArtifactFileName}.app/Contents/MacOS/ ;

cp -rf ../Resources ${BuildArtifactFileName}.app/Contents/Resources  ;

cp -rf ../Resources/Info.plist ${BuildArtifactFileName}.app/Contents/Info.plist`

This will create the directory structure, and copy everything in the projects /resources/ folder to the application bundles resources directory.

I apologize for  for answering my own question

Comment: I changed the mv to a cp as rebuilding had issues occasionally. Its also worth updating your run configuration to point to the location of the copied location, i.e. Debug/MyExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/MyExecutable otherwise you won't be able to correctly access your resources.