# How to link .obj Files into an opengl program and use them?

Tags: c++, opengl, osx-mavericks, blender

The purose of my question is, that I want .obj Files (from blender) to be available in my (opengl) program without having these visible on my hard drive. So, I imagined that it could be possible to link these .obj files into my program file and read from them. How this could be done or is it not possible? What could I do else?

Remark: the .obj files contain 3d meshes which shouldn't be editable by the user and I don't want to hard code these .obj files into a .cpp file. Working on a osx mavericks + eclipse.

Comment: Since it would probably be flagged as a link only answer, here is a script that does what you're asking for: http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/. I believe there are various file format converters that can generate C headers. This was just the first one I came across with a quick search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you can embed a file into the resources and then load them from within your software.

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm developing on a mac. Updated in my question.

Comment: Ok you can put the obj file inside the Resources into the bundle. There's some ways to encrypt the content if you don't want it to be visible, take a look at this: http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/ , it's for Iphone but it works on OSX too.

Comment: Ok, so I have to make a bundle out of my project where I have a resource folder where I can put my .obj files in. Thanks!

Comment: if you're working with a simple executable, you should seriously consider converting the obj to a cpp/h file, in that case, you can even scramble the data inside and avoid the bundle

Comment: I'm targeting to get a user-friendly app. So, I think in this case it's recommended to create a bundle and it's not that difficult to create. Because I struggled a bit with this I want to give some further readings:

Get the instructions from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131015/creating-an-application-bundle-on-osx-with-eclipse-c). An example Info.plist which is necessary to start the bundle is here: [Info.plist example](https://github.com/tmpvar/node-ogl/blob/master/deps/glfw/examples/bundle.sh)

Answer (score 0):

> The purose of my question is, that I want .obj Files (from blender) to be available in my (opengl) program without having these visible on my hard drive.

That's normally not a good idea. Image you're releasing a new version of the program, for which you have an Internet updater. If you separate the data from the program, you only have to transfer a small executable binary file. If you embed all the data into the executable every update forces you to distribute a large package.

Of course if this is some data on which your program strongly depends on and which may change between versions, that embedding it makes sense; for example configuration images of an FPGA which is connected to a microcontroller's memory interface and where the microcontroller program uses memory mapped I/O into the FPGA and the FPGA image hence must match the program.

> So, I imagined that it could be possible to link these .obj files into my program file and read from them.

Yes, this is certainly possible. The usual approach is to translate the file into a C array using a tool like [bin2c](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2c/) and compile the generated file along with your program. However keep in mind that C compilers may have an upper limit on the size an array initializers.

> What could I do else?

Don't be unreasonable. If the user can change the `.obj` file, does so, things break and the user is complaining to you, you can tell him, that after he made the changes it's upon his or her own responsibility. The user is not your enemy.

Comment: however changing models may make cheating easier in a game

Comment: also, he would like to keep the copyright on his models no ?

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini: It doesn't matter if the models are in a separate file or not, this has no effect on the copyright whatsoever. Also it's trivial to extract data from executables; just dump the contents of the `.data` section.

Comment: i did not want to intend the law aspect, but the fact that he want to hide his models to not let users to rip them..i don't see anything strange in protecting his work.

Comment: @LeonardoBernardini: Only that it doesn't work; it's a fruitless effort.